# How to replace "default" with website domain name during drush user-login

Tags: drush

When I run `drush user-login username`, drush prints a url like `http://default/user/reset/1/32323933...`. How do I replace *default* with the actual website name?

Comment: Not tried it so posting a quick comment, the variable `site_name` is used to save the name of the site in Drupal 6, the command `drush vget site_name` would give out the same, so probably `drush vset site_name WHATEVER_NAME_TO_SET` should do the work...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use option `--url`:

> `-l <http://example.com:8888>,             URI of the drupal site to use (only needed in multisite environments or when running on an alternate port).`
> `--uri=<http://example.com:8888>`

```
$  drush uli -l yoursite.dev
```

Or create a record in your [aliases.drushrc.php](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob/d9709b12d9fa1514623a49f17c8f959391243b16:/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php) file:

```
$aliases['yoursite-dev'] = array(
  'root' => '/vhosts/yoursite.dev',
  'uri' => 'yoursite.dev',
);
```

Now you have an alias `@yoursite-dev` and can use it:

```
$ drush use @yoursite-dev
$ drush uli
```

### Update:

Now I prefer to create `sites/default/drushrc.php` file for each Drupal folder:

```
<?php
$options['l'] = 'http://yoursite.dev';
$options['r'] = '/vhosts/yoursite.dev';
```

More info about `drushrc.php`: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drush-ops/drush/8.x/examples/example.drushrc.php

Answer (score 2):

I used this command for login into my local site:

```
drush uli --uri=http://your_local_url
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the uri in a [drush site alias file](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.site.yml) to avoid getting http://default at the beginning of your password reset links.

ie. **drush/sites/example.sites.yml**

```
live:
   host: server.example.com
   user: user   
   ssh: '-p 22'
   root: /home/user/public_html/docroot
   uri: 'http://example.com'
test:
   host: server2.example.net
   user: user2
   ssh: '-p 22'
   root: /home/user2/public_html/docroot
   uri: 'http://test.example.net'
dev:
   host: localhost
   user: docker
   root: /var/www/docroot
   uri: 'http://example.dev.example.com'
```

Then use the Drush site alias in the command for the password reset link:

```
drush @example.dev uli
```

The **example** after the @ symbol in the Drush site alias comes from the first part of the Drush site alias filename. The second part comes from the site entry in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could also export the environment variable DRUSH_OPTIONS_URI.

`export DRUSH_OPTIONS_URI=http://example.com`

Answer (score 0):

I work with lando and I threw together the following function:

```
duli() {
    sitename=$(lando info|grep -E https|tail -n1|cut -d \' -f2)
    lando drush uli -l $sitename;
}
```