# User added with Drush not working

Tags: 8, users, drush

So, I have to work on a D8 site I don't have a user account for. So, when I brought the code and database over to my local environment, I thought this would be an easy fix for drush.

My local dev environment is an Ubuntu server running on WSL, with php 7.2, and Drush version 8  I used the `Drush ucrt` and `urol` in the terminal, and both returned successes. I also had to temporarily deactivate the basic_auth service as the login pages weren't accessible after the move. Finally, when I tested the new user and password, it didn't work. I cleared the caches, re-set the password again, and then finally had the account blocked from too many failed attempts.

What's going on here? why didn't this work? and what do I do to make it work? I'd rather not add the user in Mysql, as I haven't seen a good tutorial for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i personally usually do with local databases is overriding the admin password:

```
drush uinf 1
```

will help you to get the user 1 name (just to be sure it is 'admin')
in that case :

```
drush upwd admin --password=MY_LOCAL_PASSWORD
```

then go to /user and try it :)

Comment: this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to log in as user 1 by using:

```
drush uli
```

https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/user/user-login/

This will generate a one-time login link:

`http://default/user/reset/1/{numbers}/{jibba-jabba}/login`

To use this, copy everything *after* `http://default` and paste it after the domain in your local dev environment.

**UPDATE:** https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/54108/80164 shows a better way to include your dev domain instead of `http://default`.

Once you're logged in as User 1, you should be able to reset the password for that account, or create a new user account for yourself.

Drush documentation: https://drushcommands.com

Comment: I have tried this route, and I'm having issues in that it's a pain in the neck to get the right URI recognized by this command (haven't set a vhost and the url gets truncated by the command).

Comment: If the URI is getting truncated, try redirecting the output to a file: `drush uli > login.txt`. Depending on your environment, you might also be able to send the output to the clipboard. Good luck!

Comment: that's a great tip! I wish there were better docs on Drush as I'm just scratching the surface

Comment: Added link to Drush documentation.

Comment: this worked like a charm, btw, tried that too!